# Python-filter numbers by using infinite or finite loops

Tags: python, loops, infinite-loop

Here are some codes I did that tried to "repeatedly reads numbers until the user enters "done", but I don't understand why I need "While true" statement to make the loop infinite in order to run "if" statement. If I don't put "While true" statement and run the code, the computer will say "'break' is out of loop" which confuses me. I also want to know under what circumstances should we use "while true" in a loop? Please help. Thanks!

```
count=0
total=0
while True:
    value=input("Enter a value:")
    if value =="done":
       break
    try:
      num=float(value)
    except:
      print("Bad input")
      continue
    count=count+1
    total=total+num
print(total,count,total/count)
```

Comment: Normally you need to find sum of some n numbers. These n numbers are read from user in each loop until user types a `'done'` which breaks the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while condition` repeats the code inside, **while the `condition` is `True`.**

In `while True`, the given condition is `True` itself, so it repeats forever on and on until in breaks(`break`).

`break` means '**Get out** of the very outside loop', so if you use `break` outside a loop, it gives you an error.

+) This is just a tip but you can use `count += 1` as for `count = count + 1`! the same goes for `total = total + num` too, like `total += num`

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the `break` statement is to stop the execution of a loop. Therefore the Python programming language requires any `break` statement to be inside a loop. So, if you leave out the `while True` statement, your `break` is not in a loop and Python properly declares an error.

There are many reasons to use a `while True` loop. One reason is to keep doing your thing until some unusual circumstance happens. Your program can check for that circumstance and stop when needed. That check can be difficult to do at the start of the loop, so using `while True` with one or more `break` statements allows checking at any point in the loop.

Another reason for a `while True` loop is to avoid repeating a statement--an application of the [Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. Your program could be done differently. You could do:

```
value = input("Enter a value:")
while value != "done":
    # the body of the loop starting with the "try" statement
    value = input("Enter a value:")
```

This format puts the check at the start of the loop, so no `True` or `break` is needed. This does have the disadvantage that you now have two `input` lines that are exactly the same and need to stay the same. If you later change your code, you could easily change one of those `input`s and forget to change the other, introducing a bug into your code. For this reason, repeating yourself is considered to be a bad thing. Current Python programming prefers to avoid the repetition and use the `while True` and `break` to avoid it.

This difficulty comes up because the program needs to execute the `input` statement one more time than it executes the loop. The loop is done for each regular input, but the `input` statement also needs to be done one more time to get the final `done` input to stop the loop. Handling that slight mismatch between the number of inputs and the number of loops is a little tricky, and there is no perfect solution. But Python has apparently settled on the `while True...break` method. For what it's worth, my programming classes 40 years ago taught us to avoid the `break` technique since that [goes against "structured programming" principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Early_exit). But those days seem to be gone.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I finally got it and you explained very well! Thank you!!!!